# "Bind Variables only allowed in Apex code" when comparing fields from two different tables

Tags: apex, soql

I'm trying to show all the leads that have the same DUNS number like the record i'm currently on (account)

```
Select l.Name, l.Email, l.CompanyDunsNumber,l.Status From Lead l
WHERE CompanyDunsNumber = (Select a.DunsNumber From Account a
Where Id='0015E00000CsMZXQA3')
```

and i receive the error:

> Bind Variables only allowed in Apex Code

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are seeing this error due to the [field to field comparison in WHERE clause of SOQL](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000187460&language=en_US&type=1).

I am not sure how you are obtaining the current Account Id but I am providing an example with this Id hardcoded (you should move away from this approach within your design) for you to move forward with.

Let's start with creating a collection of Ids to store our found "*Matching*" Leads (based on DunsNumer). You will need to iterate over the Account(s) (plural once you have redesigned to pass in a List of Account Ids to work with rather than the single hardocded Id) and then for each Account we can query the Leads that match on `DunsNumber`.

```
List<Id> leadsWithMatchingDUNS = new List<Id>();
for (Account acc : [select DunsNumber from Account where Id ='0012400000Max8P']) {
    Lead l = [select id from Lead where CompanyDunsNumber = :acc.DunsNumber];
    if (l != null) {
        leadsWithMatchingDUNS.add(l.Id);        
    }
}
System.debug(leadsWithMatchingDUNS);
```

You can follow on with this List of Lead Ids however you choose to do so. I am simply debugging for POC.

---

**Update**

After posting above solution I realized I was going against [Best Practice](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Apex_Code_Best_Practices) by perform a SOQL within a for loop.

> There is a governor limit that enforces a maximum number of SOQL
>   queries. When queries are placed inside a for loop, a query is
>   executed on each iteration and governor limit is easily reached

As of that, I have modified the code to use [Map](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_map.htm) values when querying the Lead object.

```
Map<Id, String> accountDUNS = new Map<Id, String>();
List<Id> leadsWithMatchingDUNS = new List<Id>();

for(Account acc : [
        select DunsNumber
        from Account
        where id = '0012400000Max8P']){
    accountDUNS.put(acc.Id, acc.DunsNumber);
}

for (Lead l : [
        select id,
          CompanyDunsNumber
        from Lead
        where CompanyDunsNumber = :accountDUNS.Values()]) {  
    leadsWithMatchingDUNS.add(l.Id);
}

System.debug(leadsWithMatchingDUNS.size());
```

Comment: You should not use a query inside a for loop, try using map's

Comment: @RahulSharma cheers for the spot!

Comment: First, Thanks for your fast reply, i have a few questions:
1. do you know how do i add the record id dynamically to my query? lets say i receive the record id in the function input.
2. isn't there a parameter type "Lead"? do i have to use type 'Id'?

im sorry if the questions are quiet basic or maybe dumb, im new to this :)
Thanks @PeterSmith

Comment: @D.Griff you can modify the Account query to filter by a Set of Ids such as *........ from Account where Id IN :listOfAccountIds*

Comment: @TSmith isn't there a parameter type "Lead"? do i have to use type 'Id'?